# Porting an app from Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 to 8.1

Tags: windows-embedded-compact, windows-embedded, windows-embedded-8.1

We have a RFID application running on Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5, but now some clients are asking to upgrade the app to run on 8.1
We have not done it yet, as from MSDN, it seems these two are built on different platforms, i.e. Windows Mobile 6.5 and Windows Phone 8.1 respectively.
So my question is whether we'll be able to port the application, or we need to re-write it on Windows Embedded Handheld 8.1 platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5** and **Windows Embedded Handheld 8.1** are quite different platforms in terms of writing applications. There is no automated way available to port applications from 6.5 to 8.1. I am afraid that you have to rewrite most of code. You can copy/paste same code of common libraries but would have to review it for syntax errors.